# When I pass a Texture2D as parameter to a class, this texture is null

Tags: c#, menu, xna, monogame

here is the code where I get the problem :

```
namespace Menu_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main menu screen is the first thing displayed when the game starts up.
    /// </summary>
    class MainMenuScreen : MenuScreen
    {
        #region Initialization
        ContentManager content;
        Texture2D playgame;
        Texture2D exit;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor fills in the menu contents.
        /// </summary>
        public MainMenuScreen()
            : base()
        {
            // Create our menu entries.
            MenuEntry playGameMenuEntry = new MenuEntry(playgame);
            MenuEntry exitMenuEntry = new MenuEntry(exit);

            // Hook up menu event handlers.
            playGameMenuEntry.Selected += PlayGameMenuEntrySelected;
            exitMenuEntry.Selected += OnCancel;

            // Add entries to the menu.
            MenuEntries.Add(playGameMenuEntry);
            MenuEntries.Add(exitMenuEntry);
        }

        public override void LoadContent()
        {
            if (content == null)
                content = new ContentManager(ScreenManager.Game.Services, "Content");
            Art.Load(content);

            playgame = Art.PlayGame;
            exit = Art.Exit;
            if (playgame==null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Unloads graphics content for this screen.
        /// </summary>
        public override void UnloadContent()
        {
            content.Unload();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Handle Input


        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for when the Play Game menu entry is selected.
        /// </summary>
        void PlayGameMenuEntrySelected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadingScreen.Load(ScreenManager, true, e.PlayerIndex,
                               new GameplayScreen());
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for when the Options menu entry is selected.
        /// </summary>


        /// <summary>
        /// When the user cancels the main menu, ask if they want to exit the sample.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnCancel(PlayerIndex playerIndex)
        {
            ScreenManager.Game.Exit();
        }




        #endregion
    }
}
```

So in the `MainMenuScreen()` my `playgame` is `null`, but in `LoadContent()` it is not `null`. Basically what I want to do is to pass a `Texture2D` as a parameter to the `MenuEntry` class, but the texture is null even before being passed to the class. 
You can download the full project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilcc4iea1d3zyxu/Menu%20test.rar?dl=0) if you want to try run it.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoadContent is called by XNA after your `MainMenuScreen` is initialized. You may have to defer the usage of your `playGame` object to the moment when the texture is loaded or initialize your MenuEntries in the `LoadContent`.

Comment: Well, I have to thank you very much, since I was on this problem for three days already. I don't know if initializing your `MenuEntries` in `LoadContent` is the proper way to do it, but it works at least ! Thanks again man !

Comment: @MoniqueDumon This is in fact a problem of chicken or the egg. The menu entries need contents from a method called after the constructor. Either you initialize them without the texture and then assign them a texture in the LoadContent our you simply instantiate them in the LoadContent with the texture you've just loaded.